# How do I list all new accounts created on CentOS Linux 7.2.1511

Tags: centos, security

I employed a freelancer to check my security on my server and as well as overcharging me he has behaved very unprofessionally; not outlining the work he did and indulging in sarcasm and arrogant behaviour. I'm concerned that he may have created hidden access to my server. How would I check if any hidden account was created?

Comment: Look in `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 1):

- Look at `/etc/passwd` confirm that every account listed there is one that you expect and they are correctly configured. Force all users to change passwords.
- Look at ssh configuration for each account (if it exists) and confirm that what you see is what you expect. In particular check the authorized_keys files contain only the keys you and your users expect.
- Look at the sudoers configuration. Confirm that the privileges allowed for each account are what you expect.
- Look at the /etc/ssh/sshd_config anf confirm it is what you expect.
- For each service on your system check it's configuration is what you expect. If possible check that the associated files are not tampered with.
- ...

Actually - it's probably easier to just reinstall and then recover from a known good backup.